# lavaan: Define factor by multiple variables as in Mplus

Tags: r, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I want to reduce typing-load in `lavaan`.

Imagine that you have 50 manisfest variables: `var1`, `var2,` `var3`, ... `var50`.
In M*plus* it is possible to assign a multitude of variables to a factor with the minus '-' sign like this:

```
Factor BY var1-var50;
```

Basically saying that `Factor` is defined by all 50 variables.

Is there a similar way to define the factor in `lavaan`? 
It seems that I need to state all 50 variable names:

```
model <- ' factor =~ var1 + var2 + var3 + var4 and so on...
```

Comment: This is not really a SEM question but more a basic R string manipulation question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
lvmodel <- 
paste('factor',paste(paste0('var',1:50),collapse='+'),sep='=~')
```

Comment: tnx, works. Was not aware of the existence of the convenient paste0() function.